# How to close java client socket correctly?

Tags: java, sockets, client

How to close java client socket correctly?

- is it necessary to close the socket.getOutputStream?
- is it necessary to close  the socket.getInputStream?
- is it necessary to call socket.shutdownInput () ?
- is it necessary to call socket.shutdownOutput () ?

What should be the sequence of calls (before|after) socket.close()?

Answer (score 1):

The Socket documentation states:

> Closing this socket will also close the socket's InputStream and OutputStream.

You don't have to shutdown the input/output. However that does allow you to "half" close the socket. Say if you wanted to continue to send data, but want to indicate you will no longer receive it.

So in short; It's completely fine to do the following:

```
...
finally {
    if (socket != null)
        socket.close();
}
```

Comment: Strangely, I tried debugging before asking a question, and went through all the steps of socket.close () from start to finish and did not notice that somewhere there the streams were closing. Can not look carefully ...?

Comment: Maybe streams was closed by native c++ calls... Hmm